# Can I use predefined list of values from Postgis when I draw lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, value-list

Lets say that we have 2 tables in Postgis:

```
Table 1 (PIPE):
-ID
-pipe_type_id
-geometry

Table 2 (PIPE_TYPE):
-ID
-type
```

foreign key `PIPE.pipe_type_id - PIPE_TYPE.ID`

Table PIPE is empty. Table PIPE_TYPE is filled with values.

I need to draw a line in QGIS directly to PIPE.geometry column. After the line is drawn I need a popup window to appear with an option to choose PIPE_TYPE.type value for that line. After submitting, correct value of PIPE_TYPE.ID should be stored in PIPE.pipe_type_id column.

I did this with Bentley Map using their Map Administrator and Oracle DB, but I want to try this with QGIS + Postgis. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can.  Add your `PIPE_TYPE` table to QGIS and you can use the Value Relation edit widget type on the `PIPE` table.

With you PIPE layer selected:

1. Layer -> Properties -> Fields
2. Select the `pipe_type_id` column
3. Click the Edit Widget button and select **Value relation**
4. Use the following settings:

   Layer = PIPE_TYPE

   Key Column = PIPE_TYPE.ID

   Value Column = PIPE_TYPE.type

Here is an example

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This saved me a lot of time.